# What would happen if the volume changes in first order reactions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

I am searching for any piece of hints but couldn't find out anything

What would happen if the volume changes in first order reaction?
For example, suppose there is a first order reaction of ideal gases as below
\begin{align}\ce{A (g) &-> B (g) + C (g)}& v &=k[\ce{A}]\end{align}
Then we all know that 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k[\ce{A}]$$ and $t_{1/2}$ is constant if the volume is the same.

What if the reaction is happening in a cylinder which is not fixed?
I suggest that since this is a first order reaction, the proportion of molecules which proceeds in reaction is the same every time, and the extra volume change is independent of the happening reaction, so the concentration change would get more complex, but the change of the total number of molecules would be the same as the concentration change when volume is fixed.

I am not a professional in this field so I might be wrong. If wrong, in what point?

Comment: Go back to the definitions of the various free energies and see which one applies and how that would affect your $k$.

Comment: May there be something that I don't know? In my knowledge, the constant is affected by temperature and activation energy, which are both provided constant in this situation. sorry if i didn't mention that